# Конвертировать плагин Maven в Gradle

Tags: kotlin, maven, gradle

Я работаю с библиотекой picocli и хочу создать сценарий авто завершения команд во время сборки. Дело в том, что в документации (https://picocli.info/autocomplete.html#_generating_completion_scripts_during_the_build) указан только пример плагина в Maven:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-autocompletion-script</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>java</executable>
    <arguments>
      <argument>-Dpicocli.autocomplete.systemExitOnError</argument>
      <argument>-cp</argument>
      <classpath/>
      <argument>picocli.AutoComplete</argument>
      <argument>--force</argument>
      <argument>--completionScript</argument>
      <argument>${project.build.directory}/mycommand_completion.sh</argument>
      <argument>mypackage.MyCommand</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Однако я использую Gradle и мне нужно как то адаптировать этот плагин под сборку в нём (на Котлин).
Я пробовал создавать проект с pom.xml и затем вызывать `gradle init`, но он переводит только зависимости и не учитывает плагины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по документации Gradle, плагины неконвертируемы.
Необходимо искать замену, либо писать свой.

> Replace Maven plugins with Gradle equivalents
>
> In the case of popular plugins, Gradle often has an equivalent plugin
> that you can use. You might also find that you can replace a plugin
> with built-in Gradle functionality. As a last resort, you may need to
> reimplement a Maven plugin via your own custom plugins and task types.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html